# UWP - Windows IOT - Getting files from a specific folder named "ad_runner" located in a USB drive

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I am having unhandled error show up when I am trying to access a file from a folder named "ad_runner" Which is located a USB drive. What am I doing wrong?

```
        async void AccessTheWebAsync()
    {
        StorageFolder remd = await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFolderAsync("ad_runner");
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await remd.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
        {
            dir_lbl.Text = dir_lbl.Text + "\r\n" + file.Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you put your code in a try / catch block and catch the exception that is raising (if any)? Also, have you added usb declaration in the app manifest?

Comment: Yes, I added the Removable Storage declaration.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't occur to me to do a simple try catch. The result(e.message) is showing 'Access is denied.'

However, i did enable the manifest capabilities.
https://image.ibb.co/hxkBY6/Capture.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to call `await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync();` you can see that this first call don't return the folders inside removable devices but the removable devices themself. So, I modified a little your code to first retrieve all connected removable devices and, after this, checking for inside folder named "ad_runner":

```
async void AccessTheWebAsync()
    {
        //Maybe you want to do this inside a try catch and verify that at least 1 device is connected before you go on....
        var folderList = await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync();

        foreach (var device in await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync())
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFolder remd = await device.GetFolderAsync("ad_runner");
                IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await remd.GetFilesAsync();
                foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
                {
                    //Your logic here....
                   dir_lbl.Text = dir_lbl.Text + "\r\n" + file.Name;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                rightGridWrapper.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = $"DeviceName: {device.Name}" });
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: It works! one more thing, it's showing the full path(file.Path) for each file in the contained folder(ad_runner) which again is great but when I pass that value in a list<string> format to an image URI It doesn't display the images. any reason why?
`try
            {
                BitmapImage sf = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path_x[1]));
                imagex.Source = sf;
                dir_lbl.Text = path_x[1]; //this is what i am passing from the file.path
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                dir_lbl.Text = ex.Message;
            }`

Comment: To load a file into a bitmap image you have to pass from a IRandomAccessStream, putting in simple you gain the byte[] composing your image and than you can assign the bitmapimage.source to it. you can find some help here: [link](http://windowsapptutorials.com/tips/storagefile/convert-storagefile-to-a-bitmapimage-in-universal-windows-apps/)

Comment: Maybe next time for this open another question ;)